# Create your own Open Graph Protocol type?

Tags: javascript, facebook, forms, facebook-opengraph

I'm not sure I understand Open Graph Protocol well enough to answer this question.  I'm using the `type:typeahead` feature on a [Facebook registration](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/).  The typeahead is equivalent to an input box that allows for autocomplete.

For the autocomplete suggestions, it only allows for "an array of open graph protocol types."  There are predefined arrays for [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) but can you create your own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use one of their prebuilt types that the open graph supports.  Your best option would probaby be to use a drop down list (type = select) in the field array:

```
{"name":"facebooker","description":"Pick Paul","type":"select","options":
     {"coder":"Paul","pm":"Austin","partners":"Cat"}},
```